# Weird SwitchPrefererence in PreferenceCategory auto reset behaviour

Tags: android, android-preferences

A couple of days ago i've added a new SwitchPreference to an existing android application.
Everything seemed fine, until i encountered a really weird issue - when scrolling up the settings screen - the switch preference gets auto-reseted!

When looking at the switch listener's log - it seems like the user has reverted the setting!
At this point, i tried to isolate the problem, and removed unnecessary code.

This is the simplified code:

```
public class NewSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_screen);
    }
}
```

And this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="bugger">
      <SwitchPreference
          android:title="BUGGER"
          android:key="cxyz" />
  </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="blabla">
      <Preference android:title="some1" android:key="some11" />
      <Preference android:title="some2" android:key="some12" />
      <Preference android:title="some3" android:key="some13" />
      <Preference android:title="some11" android:key="some41" />
      <Preference android:title="some12" android:key="some51" />
      <Preference android:title="some13" android:key="some16" />
      <Preference android:title="some14" android:key="some17" />
      <Preference android:title="some15" android:key="some18" />
      <Preference android:title="some16" android:key="some19" />
      <Preference android:title="some18" android:key="some199" />
  </PreferenceCategory>

  <PreferenceCategory android:title="testtest">
    <SwitchPreference
      android:title="BUGGEE"
      android:key="d" />
  </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

At this point i realized - the SwitchPreference gets reseted when it's hidden under the view, and another SwitchPreference is shown!

In order to debug that, I implemented MySwitchPreference, which extends SwitchPreference and logs every public/protected method called, but unfortunately (?) - that just fixed the problem! :)

So i have a by-pass for that, but that really interesting behaviour. Did anyone encountered something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of Android?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Checked on ICS, JB4.1, JB4.2.1, happens on all of them!

Answer (score 0):

An [answer is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744076/238374) and it has been marked as [Released on the Android bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26194) (fixed in Lollipop).

Joe's fix is to extend the SwitchPreference class and use that extension in your views. I'd summarize his workaround further but his post linked above is already quite succinct.