# Preference items being automatically re-set?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, fragment

This appears like a bug to me: When you load many switch preferences in a preference fragment, they somehow re-set themselves , when you scroll the preferences. I have separately tested this with little demo code:

---

`/res/xml/prefs.xml` (Just a bunch of switch preferences, just enough to make preferences scroll on screen) :

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:key="my_prefs">
    <PreferenceCategory android:key="my_prefs_cat" android:title="Settings">
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p1" android:title="p1" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p2" android:title="p2" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p3" android:title="p3" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p4" android:title="p4" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p5" android:title="p5" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p6" android:title="p6" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p7" android:title="p7" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p8" android:title="p8" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p9" android:title="p9" android:defaultValue="false" />
        <SwitchPreference android:key="p10" android:title="p10" android:defaultValue="false" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

---

`/src/Prefs.java` (A simple `PreferenceFragment`) :

```
package com.example.preflistbug;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}
```

---

`/res/layout/main.xml` (Placed `PreferenceFragment` in Activity layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.preflistbug.Prefs" 
        android:id="@+id/frg_prefs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

`/src/MyActivity.java` (Demo Activity) :

```
package com.example.preflistbug;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

---

**Problem:** If you change the first switch preference , scroll down, scroll back up, the switch is reset. Same is true for other switch preferences which scroll out of view and are visited later. (specially, in horizontal orientation)

Happens on emulator too. I'm compiling on platform version 15, ICS. As you can see in above code, this is a very simple setup, I can't find anything in this code, that might explain why this is happening.

#### Update

Bug reported as [Issue 26194](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26194).

#### Update 2

It is supposed to be fixed in android L release.

Comment: remove <PreferenceCategory android:key="my_prefs_cat" android:title="Settings"> this it working fine..

Comment: This doesn't appear to happen when rotated to landscape.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue. I also found a workaround but I don't know why it works :)

Create a derived class from `SwitchPreference` like so:

```
public class Pref extends SwitchPreference {
    public Pref(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Pref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Pref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }    
}
```

Then, instead of using these in your prefs.xml:

```
<SwitchPreference ... />
```

You can use these instead

```
<com.example.preflistbug.Pref ... />
```

The derivation seems to somehow fixes the issue where the view recycling in the `ListView`-driven preference list is reusing the controls without "freeing" them from their previous `Preference` object first (or so I think). I'll update this answer if I figure out more.

Comment: The fix works, pretty clever thinking :) , enjoy the bounty. I do know ListView recycling has something to do with it, but actual reasons still remain a mystery. I'd try looking up the source code and probably file a bug report. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, it's terrible but that worked. I guess Google needs to fix that bug. Thanks for that, I would have never figured that out myself!

Comment: I think the reason this works comes down to these lines in the constructor class of Preference. From api 17:
`if (!getClass().getName().startsWith("android.preference")) {
    // For subclasses not in this package, assume the worst and don't cache views
    mHasSpecifiedLayout = true;
}`

Or From api 23:
`if (!getClass().getName().startsWith("android.preference")
        && !getClass().getName().startsWith("com.android")) {
    // For non-framework subclasses, assume the worst and don't cache views.
    mCanRecycleLayout = false;
}`